# Picasso is not loading Image from URL on ASP.NET Core Web API server

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-core, picasso

I'm using Picasso in my application to load image from url and it's working fine until I decided to move all of my images into my Asp.net Core Web API server.

At first I wasn't able to access the url because I forgot to enable serving static files on my server. Followed this [information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2) I was able to access the image.

And now Picasso just can't load the image, I tried to imlement `onError` Callback and see what the error message was and it was `HTTP 404`.

My code :

```
 Picasso.get()
                .load(imageResource)
                .placeholder( R.drawable.progress_animation )
                .into(iv);
```

Is there any configuration needed on my server for picasso to access the image?

FIY : I'am able to access the image via browser, no login or authentication required

Comment: does that server follows https protocol ?

Comment: @ZubairSoomro no, I use http only

Comment: can you please provide us a sample url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried your image url to load in Image View using Picasso and its loading successfully.

I tried below code:

```
Picasso.get().load("your_image_url").into(img_user_profile, new Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        Log.w("Image Load", "Success");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception e) {
        Log.w("Image Load", "Failed");
    }
});
```

If possible can you please share your bit code where you are loading image using Picasso?

Thank you

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply, I have added the code on my post, please see it, I will try your sample when I get home, maybe the placeholder is causing the issue ? Because that's the only difference between yours and mine as I can see.

Comment: May be yes, Please try without placeholder.

Comment: Hi there, It's me again. So weird, the problem is gone, I didn't modify the code ... I just pull new source code from git hub to my home's computer and build the app again, can't understand why? Tomorrow I will re-build the app using my workplace's company to see if the problem persists. Btw, thanks for your help, I will mark yours as answer, could you please edit your answer to hide my link? I violated my company regulation by posting that link on the internet :(